# .htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, httpd, rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)

The below code adds www. to any url that does not start with it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However, I want it to do this **only** when the url is of the format:

```
something.com
```

If the url is like:

```
something.something.com
```

I do not want the rule adding www.

How do I change this?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
```

To:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(^www\.|\..+\.)
```

In other words, change your conditional from looking for "www" to looking for www *or* looking for two dots.

Though, given the problem description, this would probably work, too, and has the advantage of being simpler:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\..*\.
```

The problem could probably be described better as "rewrite any host with only one dot to prepend "www.".

Comment: Unfortunately both those changes still try to add www. to any url